# Logging the Execution times of dynamically constructed mysql stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, trigger

I have a `MySQL` Server.

The `MySQL` server contains a huge network data collection. 
The client API's will connect to the `MySQL` server and execute some dynamically created stored procedures and delete it on the fly after successful execution. 
There is no tracking mechanism currently available.
I wont be able to modify the stored procedures, as it is dynamically created by the client `API's`

Is there any mechanism to track the execution of such dynamically created stored procedures ?

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the mysqld's uptime or the DB Server's time at the start and end of your code.

Perhaps something like this

## SUGGESTION #1

```
SELECT variable_value INTO @t1
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS
WHERE variable_name='uptime';
<Your Stored Procedure Code>
SELECT variable_value INTO @t2
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS
WHERE variable_name='uptime';
SET @RunningTimeSec = @t2 - @t1;
SET @RunningTime = SEC_TO_TIME(@RunningTimeSec);
INSERT INTO sometable ... VALUES (...,@RunningTimeSec,...);
```

## SUGGESTION #2

```
SET @t1 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
<Your Stored Procedure Code>
SET @t2 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
SET @RunningTimeSec = @t2 - @t1;
SET @RunningTime = SEC_TO_TIME(@RunningTimeSec);
INSERT INTO sometable ... VALUES (...,@RunningTimeSec,...);
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 0):

Track the activity on your server with one of the off the shelf audit plugins available. McAfee Audit would be my recommendation here sincemyou likely just want to know calls filtered around the stored procs.